# Not allowed to load local resource from App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to server a larger amount of Pdf's which require authorisation in order to be able to download.

I have read that it is advisable to place them in the `App_Data` folder.

I have created three folders in the `App_Data` folder:

```
> SetOne

> SetTwo

> SetThree
```

I need to pass these files to my view.

**Controller**

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SetOne"));

return View(files);
```

**View**

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var fullPath in Model)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
        var downloadPath = @Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath) + "\\" + @fileName;
        <li><a href="@downloadPath">@fileName</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Using the above code, I am able to list the contents of the SetOne folder in an unordered list, however when I attempt to view one of the Pdf's I see:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///B:/Development/MyProject/MyProject.Web/App_Data/SetOne/sampleOne.pdf

How can I allow the application to give access to these files?

**edit**

I've also tried creating a new folder called Pdfs and moving the documents to this, however I get the same error message when I view in chrome dev tools.

Do I need to implement a Http Handler for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is OK for WinForms application but shouldn't work for Web. downloadPath should contain the Url but not the physical path on the file (like some.com/pdfs/1.pdf)

You could use [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this case

Comment: So what the best way to server PDF's from the server?

Comment: You should put the PDF's to the folder that is accessible to the User. Then you have to map the server path to get the correct URL

Comment: I have placed the pdf's in a PDF folder and I have written FileResult method called download, this returns a File, however is it now possible for people to browse directly to my PDF folder and help themselves?

Comment: You could give users the FTP Url and access to the folder.